# Getting error : Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=4

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception

I got error in following code. I am trying to save my traveled distance in SQLite Database but getting error in SQLite Database. I don't know how to manage the array length. I am getting an error called

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=4.

```
public class ActivityLocationDaoImpl extends Dao implements ActivityLocationDao {

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "activity_location";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE = "latitude";
private static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
private static final String COLUMN_ACTIVITY = "activity";
private static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
private static final String[] COLUMN_ARRAY = new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_LATITUDE, COLUMN_LONGITUDE, COLUMN_ACTIVITY, COLUMN_DATE};
public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (\n" +
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n" +
        COLUMN_LATITUDE + " INTEGER NOT NULL,\n" +
        COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " INTEGER NOT NULL,\n" +
        COLUMN_ACTIVITY + " INTEGER NOT NULL,\n" +
        COLUMN_DATE + " INTEGER NOT NULL\n" + ")";

public ActivityLocationDaoImpl(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    super(database);
}

@Override
public boolean insert(ActivityLocation activityLocation) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_LATITUDE, activityLocation.getLocation().getLatitude());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_LONGITUDE, activityLocation.getLocation().getLongitude());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_ACTIVITY, activityLocation.getActivityType().getIndex());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_DATE, activityLocation.getDate().getTime());

    return getDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues) != -1;
}

@Override
public List<ActivityLocation> listAll(Date currentDay) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(currentDay);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    currentDay = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1);
    Date nextDay = calendar.getTime();

    Cursor cursor = getDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ARRAY, COLUMN_DATE + " > ? AND " + COLUMN_DATE + " < ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(currentDay.getTime()), String.valueOf(nextDay.getTime())},
            null, null, COLUMN_DATE + " ASC", null);

    List<ActivityLocation> activityLocationList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        activityLocationList.add(convertCursorToEntity(cursor));
    }
    return activityLocationList;
}

@Override
public List<ActivityLocation> listAll(Date startDate, Date finalDate) {

    Cursor cursor = getDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ARRAY, COLUMN_DATE + " > ? AND " + COLUMN_DATE + " < ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(startDate.getTime()), String.valueOf(finalDate.getTime())},
            null, null, COLUMN_DATE + " ASC", null);

    List<ActivityLocation> activityLocationList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        activityLocationList.add(convertCursorToEntity(cursor));
    }
    return activityLocationList;
}

public ActivityLocation convertCursorToEntity(Cursor cursor) {
    ActivityLocation activityLocation = new ActivityLocation();
    Location location = new Location();

    activityLocation.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
    location.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(1));
    location.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(2));
    activityLocation.setLocation(location);
    activityLocation.setActivityType(ActivityType.values()[cursor.getInt(3)]);
    activityLocation.setDate(new Date(cursor.getLong(4)));

    return activityLocation;
}
```

Getting Error on this line :

> activityLocation.setActivityType(ActivityType.values()[cursor.getInt(3)]);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the array's size is 3, then you can only access with index 0, 1, and 2

Comment: What is the content of `cursor`?

Comment: @Jens cursor contents : `Cursor cursor = getDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ARRAY, COLUMN_DATE + " > ? AND " + COLUMN_DATE + " < ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(currentDay.getTime()), String.valueOf(nextDay.getTime())},
                null, null, COLUMN_DATE + " ASC", null);`

Comment: Can you please Show the SQL statement

Comment: @Jens COLUMN_ARRAY contents : `new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_LATITUDE, COLUMN_LONGITUDE, COLUMN_ACTIVITY, COLUMN_DATE};`

Comment: You are sure you are calling the method with the correct Cursor?

Comment: It's not the `Cursor`. It would be a different Exception. Apparently `ActivityType.values()` has only three elements, and `cursor.getInt(3)` is returning `4`.

Comment: @MikeM. Your right. I got solution. Thank you for the suggestion and time.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, the cursor only contains 3 resulting columns. Therefore you can only access 0, 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you cant access 4th element of an array having just 3 elements. Mostly people confuse this having a little background in C/C++.
This is the difference in C/C++ and JAVA. 
Suppose you have something like this:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3};
```

Now, if you do arr[3] in C/C++, it will return some garbage value, whatever is present at the that particular address, but in JAVA , ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Shravan, you can't fetch 4th index value from the array when there are only 3 values.

You can access the index values of 0,1,2 only.

Use breakpoint on the crashing line and you will get a clear picture.